# Process completed immediately after opening Terminal

Tags: macos, terminal

After I open Terminal in OS X:

```
Last login: Tue Oct 28 10:29:21 on ttys000 login(14773,0x7fff7572f300) malloc: * error for
object 0x7fd4bb715110: pointer being freed was not allocated * set a breakpoint in
malloc_error_break to debug

[Process completed]
```

I have no idea what I did or how to fix it.

Answer (score 10):

Go to Preferences → General and set Shells open with to Command, and enter the following:

```
/bin/bash -x
```

Open a new shell and see what is being run, then remove the relevant lines from your profile files.

Comment: Or, if you use zsh, you can enter `/bin/zsh -x` instead.

Answer (score 5):

1. Go to Terminal icon on Dock, press right click and press New Command
   2./bin/bash -x      (it shows your problem)
2. sudo nano .bash_profile (open this problem place)
3. delete this, Ctrl + X (exit) Yes, Enter

Comment: Your answer doesn't seem to add anything beyond grgarside's answer.

Comment: It does:  I can't enter the command in the path grg proposes.  And JustGo's answer gave me a way I could run shell commands to fix the issue.  I couldn't even crack-open the dot-files in a text editor: Apple "helpfully" doesn't expose them in finder.  So if your shell is terminating as quickly as you open it as is the case with this issue, this is a way in-

Comment: In my case new command -> `/bin/bash -x` also opens a terminal window with `[Process completed]`

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old...but I had the same problem, and couldn't find any information to fix this issue, so I decided to share the solution here too.

Hopefully it helps someone else. :)

After upgrading a Mac from OS X 10.6.8 (Snow Leopard) to 10.11.4 (El Capitan), it would no longer open a shell in Terminal. It would open a Terminal Window with only [Process completed] displayed on the screen.

The Console log showed the errors:

```
login: in openpam_load_module(): no pam_serialnumber.so found
login: pam_start(): system error
```

This post (https://discussions.apple.com/message/11861278#11861278) pointed me in the right direction.

I checked the contents of /private/etc/pam.d/login.term on the affected Mac, and on a working Mac.

Broken Mac Terminal /private/etc/pam.d/login.term

```
# login: auth account password session
auth       optional       pam_krb5.so
auth       optional       pam_mount.so
auth       sufficient     pam_serialnumber.so serverinstall legacy
auth       required       pam_opendirectory.so
account    required       pam_nologin.so
account    required       pam_opendirectory.so
password   required       pam_deny.so
session    required       pam_uwtmp.so
session    optional       pam_mount.so
```

Working Mac Terminal /private/etc/pam.d/login.term

```
# login: account session
account    required       pam_nologin.so
account    required       pam_opendirectory.so
session    required       pam_uwtmp.so
```

I edited the contents of the Mac with the broken Terminal to match the Mac with the working Terminal, and Terminal immediately started working correctly.

Answer (score 1):

None of the other solution worked for me. It seems that my terminal was spitting out process completed because I was low on disk space. Deleting files didn't help. I had to delete my time machine local snapshots.

Answer (score 0):

This could be something as simple as some borked permissions. I was having some issues starting up a shell when I migrated a machine to Yosemite, and a permission repair took care of the problem.

Try to use the "Repair Permissions" function on your startup disk using Disk Utility.app. Hopefully, as it's running, the log window will show a series of files with incorrect permissions. If you have more than one or two files with bad permissions, rinse and repeat until you get a clean log.

Note: occasionally there will be some files that trip up the repair utility (can't recall specifics at the moment), but on a new Mac mini, you should be able to get a clean run on the second or third try.

Answer (score -1):

The following solved it for me:

1. Go to: Terminal > Preferences
2. Scroll down to: Shell
3. Change, `/bin/bash` to: `/bin/sh`

Answer (score -1):

1. Go to Terminal icon on Dock, press right click and press New Command
2. `/bin/bash -x` , and reopen Terminal (it shows your problem)
3. Go to Preferences → General and set Shells open with to Command, and enter the following: `/bin/sh`
4. Close the Terminal Preferences window
5. Open Terminal again (it should work)
6. `vi /Users/<your_user>/.bash_profile`, remove the lines found in step 2.
7. Go to Preferences → General and set Shells open with to Command, and enter the following: `/bin/bash`
8. Open Terminal, it should work now