# Strange Terminal behavior "[Process completed]"

Tags: terminal, zsh

After migrating my Macbook Air M1 to my new Macbook Air M2 using the Migration Assistant, my zsh Terminal seems broken in a strange way.

The terminal is set to run the script `~/.zshrc` on startup. This script was migrated from the old machine, where it worked flawlessly.

On the new machine, a new Terminal always opens with `[Process completed]`, and I'm not able to do anything in it.

So I opened `~/.zshrc` in an editor and removed everything. Opening a terminal now results in

```
[Command not found: ~/.zshrc]

[Could not create a new process and open a pseudo-tty.]
```

(Uh, what? An empty file counts as a "Command not found"?)

Then I added `echo "hello"` to the file:

```
hello

[Process completed]
```

Why do I get `[Process completed]`? In [similar](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/377955/process-completed-immediately-after-opening-terminal-and-impossible-to-add-comma) [questions](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/153408/process-completed-immediately-after-opening-terminal), the problem could be solved by emptying the `~/.zshrc` contents.

But I get the problem even if the contents of the `~/.zshrc` file are trivial.

Comment: Ah, just noticed: "The terminal is set to run the script ~/.zshrc on startup": What do you mean with that, did you add something specific to Terminal for this?

Comment: @nohillside no, I just mean that if you go to the Terminal Preferences, you see `~/.zshrc` in the "Shell opens with" --> "Command (complete path):" textbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to specify `.zshrc` in Terminal Preferences. Just set it to either the default shell or to the path of your shell binary.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Strange that this worked on my Macbook Air M1, but not on the new M2 one.

Comment: @cheesus Strange indeed. But glad I could help.